# How do I get the name of the parent of a UI Game Object in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity which is mainly made up of UI. The UI is made up of a lot of parent gameobjects with buttons below them in the hierarchy. I require getting the name of the parent (an empty gameobject) when clicking on the button. So far I have tried this:

```
CountryText.text = transform.parent.name;
```

But it has not worked. Is there something I can do to make this work?

Comment: what does this `transform.parent.name` return?

Comment: What exactly does `has not worked` mean?

Comment: @TomSebty It just returns an error with the message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

Comment: @Catty01well that means that the object you are using this code on doesn't have a parent but is rather a root object in your scene .. apparently this is either not the object you think it is or your object doesn't have the parent you think it should have ...

Comment: Place all objects inside a parent. Does this return a result now?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are not talking about the parent, since `transform.parent` would have been the answer, but one of the ancestors in the hierarchy, a good approach would be to tag the specific object using the `gameObject.tag` and traverse the hierarchy.
You can assign tag in the inspector, and execute a search by calling:

```
public Transform FindParentWithTag(Transform child, string tag)
{
    Transform next = child;
    while (next.parent != null)
    {
        if (next.parent.tag == tag)
        {
            return next.parent;//found ancestor with tag
        }
        next = next.parent.transform;
    }
    //search failed
    return null;
}
```

Comment: OP already said in the comments that `not working` in this case means getting a `NullReferenceException` .. you shouldn't post answers based on assumptions ;) Besides that there are better ways of getting a specific parent .. and also better ways of getting a specific parent with a certain tag ;)

Comment: @derHugo Looking for a parent by on tags is better than by a name. This is a step up from the presented approach.
My answer also covered the null reference issue OP had, so I might have to drop the phrasing.
I didn't feel the need to overwhelm the OP by providing all the possible ways to get it done.

Comment: What I mean is: There are many fancy ways of finding a certain parent object dynamically .. but actually the original issue here is that OP's object simply has no parent at all .. in which case your method here still returns `null` => exactly same issue. This is not fully your answers fault but caused by the fact that this question is basically off-topic since `does't work` is not a well enough information for us to answer properly. The answer would be: "Your object doesn't have any parent but you are trying to access it". That's why I say you shouldn't answer based on assumptions.